# How to change AutoPowerOff Enabled in OSX?

Tags: macos, shutdown, system-info

My mac has been unwantedly shutting down when I leave it closed and unplugged recently. I'm guessing this is because of the AutoPowerOff Delay and AutoPowerOff Enabled settings:

[image]

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to change those settings. How do I change those settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this because my 2010 MacbookPro doesn't list "AutoPowerOff" in the system report, but you should be able to turn off that feature by opening a terminal and running the following command.

`sudo pmset -a autopoweroff 0`

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4622383?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I don't know why but my iMac started to auto power off too after installing High Sierra, nice finding here!